# in-app Apple subscription...can't find information about the "Share your information" feature

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now that Apple has changed their in-app subscription model, there is a feature that allows a user to share their information when they confirm their subscription. The message below is displayed after a user confirms their subscription purchase:

"Share your information"
"The developer would like your name, email and zipcode so they can send you messages about related products in accordance with their privacy policy."

I have the Apple In-App purhcase programming Guide and I can't find *anything* about how this 'data' about the user is returned or retrieved by the developer. Is it returned in the JSON string when verifying a receipt?

Comment: Is this feature only available on 'The Daily'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this information is not passed or shared with the app via the API or any delegates. Apple collects this data themselves with the user and shares it via a backend admin. No programming is necessary to handle this feature.

Comment: Where did you find this information and what exactly do you mean by "backend admin"? ITunesConnect?